# Prove that this set is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Consider the set $E = \{a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3+ d\sqrt6 : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. I want to show $E$ is a field, but I don't know how to prove every element in $E$ has an inverse. Would you please give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: since $E=\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}][\sqrt{3}]$, first prove $\Bbb F[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field if $\Bbb F=\Bbb Q$, then use the same technique to prove $\Bbb F[\sqrt{3}]$ is a field if $\Bbb F=\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: (Ignorant) alternative approach.  I don't know from Field Theory.  This would be my first try, which may have analytical holes in it:  Every element of the form $(a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6})$ can be converted into an element of the form $(a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3})$ by multiplying it by $(a - d\sqrt{6}).$  Then, see what happens if a number of form $(a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3})$ is multiplied by $(a - b\sqrt{2} - c\sqrt{3}).$  Then, see what happens if a number of form $(a + b\sqrt{6})$ is multiplied by $a - b\sqrt{6}.$ Then, you can compute $(a) \times (1/a).$

Comment: Write it as $(a+b\sqrt {2})+\sqrt {3}(c+d\sqrt{2})$ and then multiply and divide by a similar expression which uses $-\sqrt {3}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}$. This would generate an expression of type $A+B\sqrt{2}$. Then multiply and divide by its conjugate